# python: a case for "from module import *"?

Tags: python, import

I know why it's a bad idea, but this seems a good case for it, and I want to hear why I'm wrong, and what my alternatives are.

I have thing.py which is full of core logic.

I have appthing.py which wants to use that logic, while adding some app-specific things for the environment we use, like saving user settings regarding said logic through our app's built-in, persistent storage capabilities, which appthing.py would interact with to restore state at later times, and so on.

I can (as I see it):

1. duplicate thing.py's function names in appthing.py; these call the originals
2. call things where they are: appthing.func1, appthing.thing.func2, etc
3. import both and use them in parallel somehow
4. from thing import * and work with appthing.funcs everywhere

I don't want to do 1 - I hate duplication of code/work. 2 seems a bear to work with (appthing.settingA becomes appthing.thing.settingA). 3 seems like a bad idea in general. That leaves 4, import *, which I know is wrong, but again, in this case it seems okay.

What say you? What's my option 5? Thanks.

I should note that there aren't any classes anywhere. I'm trying to break the habit of classes everywhere. None of this needs it, so simply subclassing between modules is out.

Comment: Instead of a text written explanation, could you provide a brief simplified sample of your code?

Comment: Please read the FAQ sections on questions not to ask. This question solicits opinions and there is no right answer, so it's not considered on-topic for this site.

Comment: I'm sorry, agf. I thought there would be a correct answer to this one, i.e. a standard way to handle this particular issue. That's what I hoped option 5 would be.

Answer (score 2):

5) Import only those functions you know you'll use

6) Go all the way with object-orientation and make `thing` and `appthing` classes, where `appthing` inherits from `thing`

---

The choice is yours, really. What do you think is best? Consider especially the need to maintain the code. What happens if `thing` needs to change some functionality? How does that affect `appthing`'s users?

In your scenario, I would probably choose my own option 5. That way it's explicit what I inherit and a change in `thing` which doesn't affect `appthing` can be made without me going through code using `appthing`.

I would not go with number 1, because that's really cumbersome. Be pragmatic and choose a design which scales and can be maintained easily.

Comment: Thanks, Emil. I'm definitely avoiding number 1.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to do:

```
from mymodule.thing import my_settings as settings
#...
# use the name settings everywhere in this client code
```

This way you have only one place to update if your `mymodule` interface changes (DRY principle).

Option 4 (`from mymodule import *`) makes your client code brittle to any future changes in `mymodule` and also introduces opportunities for name clashes. If you are confident that there will be no name clashes, and that you wont be updating your 'core' module often, then it is fine; just be aware that there is a direct dependency in your client code.

Answer (score 1):

This is acceptable where you have a module the provides only things that can happily be seen in the importing module, and where there is only one such module.

For example, in my django projects, I like to import everything from `models` into `views`, which brings in all of my models, and other classes like django's own `User` class as unqualified names into the view code. This is convenient, as the `view` module will always be coupled to the `models` module. I don't do this for any other pair of modules.

Comment: Thanks, Marcin. The difficult thing here is that there is very little in appthing.py - it's really only to add a few things like saving settings. I'd just put them in thing.py, but then there's app-specific code in library-level code that I have to try/except around, which gets really messy. I really don't want to import *. I just want while in the app to have a few extra abilities tacked onto thing.py. thing.py is very low-level stuff. It imports from nothing else.

Comment: @GaryFixler It sounds like you've thought about this, and concluded it's unlikely to cause problems. Go for it. Your alternative would be to use something like the django conf system to copy all of the variables in a module into an object.